# JWT: Does the client need both the Public and Private keys?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I have a REST API (C# .Net Core).  I would like to implement JWT Authorization.  What is unclear to me is whether the client application that consumes the API needs both the Private and Public keys, or if the client should only have the Public key.

When I call my "authorization" API, should the client send just the public key, and have the server use its Private key to build the token that is returned to the client?

I have it working now, but I'm starting to question having the client pass both the public and private keys to the "Authorization" API.

Comment: No the client doesn't need both. You've described the process fine. The client should use the public key to verify the JWT. It makes sense that the client would only send the public key to the auth-api as the server/API would create and sign the JWT using the public/private key pair.

Answer (score 0):

> the client application that consumes the API needs both the Private
> and public keys, or if the client should only have the public key.

`JSON Web Token (JWT)` is primarily used to perform stateless authentication. The client just needs to obtain the token, store it and sends it with every request to the server. It's server responsibility to first get the token from incoming request then parse/validate the token, extract the information and perform the authentication.

`JSON Web Signature (JWS)` and `JSON Web Encryption (JWE)` are the implementations of JWT. In JWS, auth server uses the single key to sign the data. Thanks to the sign/signature, integrity of token's data remains intact, but one can see the data if they've access to the token. On the other hand, in JWE, auth server uses both private and public keys while generating the token. `Public key` is used for encrypting the token's data and `Private key` for signing the encrypted data. So, addressing both integrity as well as content visibility concerns. One should go with JWE, where token content contains the sensitive data.

In the aforementioned information we didn't use anything from the client side. So, if your use case is just similar to describe above, you don't need to use any key from the client end.

Comment: If the client does not need a key, what would prohibit anyone from requesting a token?  How does that jive with the whole "authorization" scheme?  This cannot be correct.

Comment: Client would be registered in the auth server and issued a key/client id using which they will make request to auth server to get the token.